# In which order SELECT query return the results?

Tags: sql, database

Can some one explain to me how the SELECT return the results??. Does it preserve the order when returning the results when I run the same query over and over again(maybe after updating some fields) ??

Comment: @TimSchmelter why is it a dumb question?? Or a question can't give a direct answer??.. Can you explain a bit??.

Comment: Your question is to vague. Like it is, the answer might be "It depends!" to all questions.

Comment: 1 ) it generates all possible results. 2) from these, it filters, leaving only records that exist in the FROM table(s) 3) from this it filters leaving only the records that satisfy the WHERE clause. Since the records in step#1 are unordererd, the result is also unordered.

Comment: Use an "order by" clause and then it doesn't matter. From my experience, the order results are returned is completely uncontrollable. If the data is unchanged, it should be the same each time. But if there have been inserts or deletes then order can be anything. It all depends where the memory is available.

Comment: It is a valid and answerable question. Why the downvotes?

Comment: @Quassnoi That's my fault. I didn't ask the question clearly..  that's why :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In no specific order (unless you specify `ORDER BY` clause).

When they write it in the manuals, they mean it.

Depending on the implementation of a certain `RDBMS`, a `SELECT` query can change its plan on statistics recalculation, as a result of a tablespace reallocation, as a result of changes in query parallelization and for a million other reasons.

Even if you do nothing with the table and run two exactly same queries one after another, the records may be returned in completely different order.

Comment: Is it better to use a timestamp to preserve the records changed order? So whenever I use "ORDER BY TIMESTAMP" it preserve the changed order. Am I correct??..

Comment: @Aruna: `TIMESTAMP` means different things in different engines. If you have entries with duplicate timestamps their order (within a timestamp) is undefined. Use `ORDER BY timestamp, primary_key_column` (or any other column unique along with the timestamp) if you want persistent order.

Comment: @Quassoni Thanks for the descriptive answer. It cleared a lot of doubts in my mind. Really appreciate your help.