# Exclude current row in average calculation

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with two columns: parties and their respective spendings (party and per_capita). I have to return a table with the column of the parties and the average of all the spedings done by them if the party in the column is not used in the calculation: so, supose I have x, y and z. I want something like:

```
X | Average of spendings of (Y,Z)
Y | Average of spendings of (X,Z)
Z | Average of spendings of (X,Y)
```

I tried the following, resulting in NULL for the spending columns:

```
SELECT pcp.party, avg(pcp.per_capita) OVER (PARTITION BY pcp.party ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW) AS average
FROM per_capita_party pcp
ORDER BY average DESC;
```

Comment: Each partition only has one row in it.  If you exclude that row, the position is empty

Answer (score 2):

You can use lateral for doing this. For example:

```
select distinct symbol,v
from myTable t1, lateral (
   select avg(amount) 
   from myTable t2 where t1.symbol != t2.symbol) t(v);
```

Here is [DBFiddle demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4c0d850bd3b03527bc87909dee642192)

Answer (score 1):

A [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) will do the job close to natural language.

```sql
SELECT pcp.party,
 (select avg(per_capita) from per_capita_party where party <> pcp.party) average
FROM per_capita_party pcp
ORDER BY average DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use window function exclude group frame clause.
Based on Cetin's DBfilddle.
new [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0a801b7b11e28aa91beb3a1263cde486)

```
SELECT
    symbol,
    avg(amount) OVER (ORDER BY symbol GROUPS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING EXCLUDE GROUP)
FROM
    mytable;
```

or

```
SELECT
    symbol,
    avg(amount) OVER (ORDER BY symbol DESC GROUPS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING EXCLUDE GROUP)
FROM
    mytable;
```

Comment: It should be: `SELECT symbol, avg(amount) OVER (ORDER BY symbol GROUPS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING EXCLUDE GROUP) FROM mytable ORDER BY 2;`, and, when ordering descending, `ORDER BY 2 DESC`.  (see: [In which order SELECT query return the results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301649/in-which-order-select-query-return-the-results))