# MySQL ORDER columns by empty last but without alphabetical order

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to order columns by empty string last. For example.

```
 comment 
--------------------------
 Apple
 ''
 Orange
 Avocado
 Banana
 Cauliflower
 Broccoli
 ''
 Potato
 Cabbage
```

The order should be like this without alphabetical order

```
     comment 
    --------------------------
     Apple     
     Orange
     Avocado
     Banana
     Cauliflower
     Broccoli   
     Potato
     Cabbage
     ''
     ''
```

but what I'm getting is

```
     comment 
    --------------------------
     Apple 
     Avocado     
     Banana
     Broccoli 
     Cauliflower
     Cabbage
     Orange
     Potato         
     ''
     ''
```

I tried many queries  with if, case .etc  but all of them were ordered alphabetically

some of the solutions I tried

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` order by  NULLIF(NULLIF(comment ,'0'),''),comment desc;

SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY IF(comment IS NULL, 1,0), comment desc;

SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY case when comment is null then 1 else 0 end,
    comment desc
```

Comment: "without alphabetical order" meaning what exactly? Specifically "in random order"? In case the ordering is unspecified, your last and second-to-last example are indistinguishable.

Comment: [In no specific order (unless you specify ORDER BY clause)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10301950/724039).  Your database (or a database) does not know how to do **without alphabetical order**.

Comment: Your problem is that you don't have a (primary) key column that reflects the internal ordering of the rows (the 'clustering'). Usually this 'unordered' state you want to preserve is the order in which the rows have been inserted. A sequential value, like an increasing `int` ID would reflect this and enable you to write an `ORDER BY` clause with it. Without that the `UNION ALL` approach in the answers below is probably the only thing that could work, but it's not good.

Comment: One thing you still could try is to just leave the `comment` column out of the `ORDER BY`. So just `ORDER BY IF(comment IS NULL, 1, 0)`, and see what happens. But it really depends on the database whether or not the original order of the two groups will be preserved or not...

Comment: @OliverSchimmer: When an index exists, output might still be ordered, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/ssUvcVEs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried checking if `comment` column is empty string in conjunction with checking for `null`?

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY if(comment = '' or comment is null,1,0)
```

or using trim method

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY if(trim(comment) is null,1,0)
```

Also I noticed in the table, you showed the column name is `NAME` instead of `comment`, just want to clarify if the column name is either `NAME` or `comment`? If it's `NAME`, the query should reflect that

Comment: When an index exits on `comment`, the order of the result is still alphabetical, this is not wat is asked about.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

You can simply use `(name ='')` as order by clause which will return 1 if name is empty other wise 0.

```
select * from comments order by (name ='')
```

If you have `null` as well then you can use:

```
select * from comments order by (NULLIF(name,'') is null)
```

Here `NULLIF(name,'')` will convert empty string into null

You can select rows without empty strings first without any order. Then you can select the rows with empty strings. You can combine both the results with `union all`

Query:

select * from comments where name <>''
union all
select * from comments where name =''

Output:

| name |
| --- |
| Apple |
| Orange |
| Avocado |
| Banana |
| Cauliflower |
| Broccoli |
| Potato |
| Cabbage |
|  |
|  |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u75I0Nmw)

Better approach would be to use conditional order clause like below:

Query:

select * from comments order by (case when name ='' then 1 else 0 end)

Output:

| name |
| --- |
| Apple |
| Orange |
| Avocado |
| Banana |
| Cauliflower |
| Broccoli |
| Potato |
| Cabbage |
|  |
|  |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Be2Z1dQn)

Comment: This answer is slow, error-prone, and actually wrong.

Comment: The blanks are still not guaranteed to be at the bottom without an order by

Comment: When an index exists, output might still be ordered, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/ssUvcVEs